# Getting Forbidden 403 error while creating OnlineMeeting using Microsoft Graph v1.0 SDK

Tags: c#, api, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am trying to create online meeting to get the joinurl from Microsoft Team Meeting using Graph SDK but I am getting Forbidden (403) error even after I had provided Application (With Admin Consent) and delegation permission to "OnlineMeetings.Read.All", "OnlineMeetings.Read", "OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite.All", "OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite".

Please see my code below and let me know what I am doing wrong or whether I need to provide any other permissions.

Below is my code :

```
 string[] graphScopes = { "OnlineMeetings.Read.All", "OnlineMeetings.Read", 
    "OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite.All", "OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite" };

        IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create("55e5f6cf-****-****-****-4f23d6e****")
            .WithTenantId("****b9d4-4dbf-****-888f-21d*563b****")
            .WithClientSecret("********************************")
            .Build();


        ClientCredentialProvider authenticationProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);

        GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authenticationProvider);

        var onlineMeeting = new OnlineMeeting
        {
            StartDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2020-01-15T21:30:34.2444915+05:30"),
            EndDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2020-01-15T22:00:34.2464912+05:30"),
            Subject = "User Token Meeting"
        };

        var meeting = graphClient.Me.OnlineMeetings
              .Request()
              .AddAsync(onlineMeeting).Result;
```

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: Did you get the solution? @Gopi

Answer (score 1):

[Create onlineMeeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions) only requires `OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite` **Delegated** Permission.

So it requires user + app authorization rather than app-only authorization.

In this case, you are using [Client credentials provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=CS#client-credentials-provider), which means app-only authorization.

You should use [Authorization code provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=CS#authorization-code-provider) to get the access token, which will include `OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite` **Delegated** Permission.

Comment: Can you help me on this?    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62555532/create-a-event-as-online-meeting-using-microsoft-graph-api