# How to integrate OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite scope in Microsoft Graph API

Tags: php, api, outlook, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I've been facing issues while integrating **OnlineMeeting** scope from Microsoft's Graph API for many days and have explained my issue below in detail:

1. I've inserted these scope[ ***OnlineMeetings.Read*** and
   ***OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite*** ] in my App Registration in API permissions in **Azure** Platform for generating Access Tokens through Oauth Flow.
2. After that, I've added that into the **Expose an API section** tab in Azure Platform.
3. I've coded the logic in PHP and then after I've passed the scopes in the URL section for generating Oauth code and after there, took the code from URL and processed it ahead for generating access tokens along with refresh and scopes valid for the tokens.
4. After that, the tokens are received from the curl are working fine for Calendar, email, profile but not for OnlineMeeting scope as this particular scope is not shown in the response of it. [See this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8rTh.png)
5. If these access tokens are used for OnlineMeeting create API then I would get the **400** error for Bad request. [See this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sG364.png)

Would be great if anyone who has gone through this, would come forward and help me out!

Comment: As per the [ask] guide, you must not post pictures of code and data. Please edit your question to include everything as _text_. Pictures of code make life difficult for those trying to help because it cannot be copied and pasted, searched, etc. Pictures can be used if you need to illustrate a UI problem or something like that. If you're new to stackoverflow please also take the [tour] (as you were already recommended to do before posting). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please checknthese

1. Make sure to login with work or school account as OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite is not supported for personal accounts.
2. Check if access policy needs to be configured >  [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/cloud-communication-online-meeting-application-access-policy#configure-application-access-policy)    and makesure to grant the access policy to the user and give application permissions.
3. Try with Microsoft graph v1.0 endpoint instead of beta endpoint.
4. And make sure you have proper licenses if it is with teams

References:

1. [create online meetings-MicrosoftGraph-v1.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)
2. [SO reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62555532/create-a-event-as-online-meeting-or-only-the-onlinemeeting-using-microsoft-gra/66821621#66821621)

Comment: Thanks, @kavyasaraboju-MT for the help. I'll check this once and is there any API that could return which type of account now is using i.e. personal, work, or school account?